# List all remote branches in git not working

Tags: git

I want to list all the remote branches in git through command line. I typed the command `git remote -v`, but it didn't show any branches. I have just pulled the project and I want to list all remote branches. `git branch -a` also doesn't show up anything.

[image]

Comment: `git branch -a` will show all local and remote branches. `git remote -v` will show all remotes (without their branches)

Comment: It looks like you have not added a remote to this repo...

Comment: did you add any remote?
try adding the origin url using `git remote add origin whatever_the_url_is`

Comment: Try it, it'll surely work

Comment: How did you initially clone the repository?

Comment: Yes, if you used a git daemon and then removed the remote, it might have led to the problem in the first place.

Comment: @vijayrana: was one of the answers below helpful for you? If so, please consider accepting one of them. To do so, click the tick mark to the left, so it turns green. This is how we mark questions resolved here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

As `git remote -v` does not show anything it is clear that your git repository has no remote. Add one!

Try adding the origin url using `git remote add origin whatever_the_url_is`

Comment: BTW: that your `git branch -a` does not even return your local branch `master` looks as if your repository is empty. For example when you `mkdir X && cd X && git init` and then call `git branch -a` on this new-born repository, it will exactly show nothing! You need an inital commit.

Answer (score 2):

As per the git-branch [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

```
 git branch --list -r
```

or to list both remote and local

```
git branch -a
```